# Find duration between login and logout of each user

Tags: sql, datetime

The status 1 means Login and Status 0 means Logout. How do I find sum of each  duration between the login and logout of each user?

**Here's the table**

user_id            time                        status

```
11              2015-10-21 10:00:00         1       
11              2015-10-21 10:14:00         0              
3              2015-10-21 12:30:00         1       
4              2015-10-21 12:45:00         0
```

Comment: You could self-join the table on a.status!=b.status (and the other relevant columns), compute the time difference between the interval and choose the smallest positive difference.

Comment: Any tutorial or a related SO solution that can help me on implementing the solution you provided? I have very little knowledge on mysql.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure, that there are no invalid intervals (broken sessions without a logout?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about that!

Comment: Given that the term `self join` was given to you, a google search on that term would lead you to the examples you requested.

Comment: @DanBracuk I know joins,self joins and almost all joins but I do not know how to use them altogether  to find the solution.

Comment: Hi, if one of these answers could help you to solve your problem, it would be very kind to vote helpful answers up and mark the most helpful as accepted. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Given that all data are valid you can give this sandbox-example a try:

```
select a.uid, a.d, b.d, min(timediff(b.d, a.d)) from (
    select 55 as uid, '2015-10-21 08:00:00' as d, 1 as lflag
    union all
    select 55 as uid,  '2015-10-21 09:00:00' as d, 0 as lflag   
    union all
    select 55 as uid,  '2015-10-21 12:00:00' as d, 1 as lflag  
    union all
    select 55 as uid,  '2015-10-21 14:00:00' as d, 0 as lflag   
) a
left join (
    select 55 as uid, '2015-10-21 08:00:00' as d, 1 as lflag
    union all
    select 55 as uid,  '2015-10-21 09:00:00' as d, 0 as lflag         
    union all
    select 55 as uid,  '2015-10-21 12:00:00' as d, 1 as lflag  
    union all
    select 55 as uid,  '2015-10-21 14:00:00' as d, 0 as lflag   
) b
on (a.uid=b.uid and a.lflag=1 and b.lflag = 0)
where timediff(b.d, a.d) > 0
group by a.uid, a.d
```

This gives the output:

```
55 2015-10-21 08:00:00  2015-10-21 09:00:00 01:00:00
55 2015-10-21 12:00:00  2015-10-21 14:00:00 02:00:00
```

Comment: sorry for saying this but I'm ignorant on how to use this code on my data :(

Comment: I was to lazy to create a table with your data , so the stuff between from ( ) and left join () actually is your table.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT tbl.UserID,tbl.Dt,(SELECT TOP 1 x.Dt 
                          FROM YourTable AS x 
                          WHERE x.UserID=tbl.UserID AND LogStatus=0 AND x.Dt>tbl.Dt 
                          ORDER BY Dt ASC)
FROM YourTable AS tbl
WHERE tbl.LogStatus=1
ORDER BY tbl.UserId,tbl.Dt;
```